# Who are the three people John Wick is hunting down?

Tags: plot-explanation, john-wick-chapter-4

In the desert region, John Wick is riding on a horse and trying to shoot
three people, who are each riding their own horses and escaping from him.

[image]

Who are the three people John Wick is hunting down?

Comment: Some lackeys of his real target.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### We don't know

The [screenplay](https://deadline.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/12/John-Wick-Chapter-4-Read-The-Screenplay.pdf) only identifies them as Riders 1, 2 & 3 with no other information given.

*Presumably* they are working for The Elder; the One Who Sits Above the Table since they knew where we was.